# I need x on x axis y on y axis and fx and fy in plot area in R

Tags: r, plot, label, axis-labels

I need this type of figure: 
[image]

I need x on x axis, y on y axis and fx and fy in ploy area. Could you please help me in R i.e. both curves intersect to each other. My code is

```
   gx <- expand.grid(x=seq(1,5,length=50))
   fx <- function(x) { exp(-x) }
   gx$fx <- apply(gx,1,fx)
   plot(gx, type="l",col="red")

   gy <- expand.grid(y=seq(1,5,length=50))
   fy <- function(y) { y*exp(-y) }
   gy$fy <- apply(gy, 1, fy)
   par(new=TRUE)
   plot(gy, type="l", col="green")
```

[image]

Comment: If you're asking about x,y-labels, then please say that. It would help if you posted the image of the current plot and explain what you expected to see differently. "fx, fy in plot area"? Do you want to see text showing the numerical value of fx, fy placed at the corresponding points in the lot area?

Comment: Change your last line to `lines(gy, col="green")`. This will add it to the previous plot.

Comment: Than you for your response Andrew Gustar. I need x,  fx according to x axis and y, fy according to y axis in a single plot.

Comment: Please check your function for `f(x)`. It's definitely not giving you the calculation as what you require.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure I understand what this question means, but if you are looking to label your axes you can use the xlab and ylab graphical parameters:

ie:

```
plot(gx, type="l",col="red", xlab="label for x axis", ylab="label for y axis")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the plot with base:

```
plot(gx, type="n", xlab="", ylab="")
for(i in 1:2) lines(get(c("gx", "gy")[i]), col=c("red", "green")[i])
title(xlab="x", ylab="y")
```

[image]

I personally prefer to do a little bit more data-manipulation to combine both data (`gx` and `gy`) into a single data.frame in long-form using "dplyr" and "tidyr" packages :

```
dat <- data.frame(gx, gy)
dat <- dat %>% 
      gather(xvar, x, x,y) %>% 
      gather(yvar, y, fx, fy)
head(dat)

#   xvar        x yvar         y
# 1    x 1.000000   fx 0.3678794
# 2    x 1.081633   fx 0.3390415
# 3    x 1.163265   fx 0.3124642
# 4    x 1.244898   fx 0.2879703
# 5    x 1.326531   fx 0.2653964
# 6    x 1.408163   fx 0.2445921
```

This will make it easy to visualise with ggplot:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y, col=yvar)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use of `legend` and `lines` functions along with `plot` would give the following figure.

```
plot(gx,type="l",col="red", xlab ="x", ylab="y")
lines(gy,col="green")
legend("topright", inset=.05, cex = 1, c("f(x)","f(y)"), horiz=TRUE, lty=c(1,1), lwd=c(2,2), col=c("red","green"), text.font=3)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem anyone so far has answered about putting f(x) and f(y) in the plot area. You can do this with `text()`, though it's not the most elegant solution because you have to manually give the coordinates of where to place the text.

The data you gave:

```
gx <- expand.grid(x=seq(1,5,length=50))
fx <- function(x) { exp(-x) }
gx$fx <- apply(gx,1,fx)

gy <- expand.grid(y=seq(1,5,length=50))
fy <- function(y) { y*exp(-y) }
gy$fy <- apply(gy, 1, fy)
```

Creating the plot:

```
plot(gx,type="l",col="red", xlab ="x", ylab="y")
lines(gy,col="green")
text(x=c(3,2),y=c(0.18,0.1), labels=c("f(y)","f(x)"))
```

Gives this:

[image: figure with axis and plot area labels]

I hope this helps! The part that is confusing about your question is when you say that you need the lines to intersect. That's an issue with your data and/or the functions you are applying, and not one we can answer without some clarity.